# C# Regex: Find All Calls to Other Stored Procedures In Procedure File

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, comments

I am trying to find all the names of the stored procedures called in a stored procedure file. A valid stored procedure call is:

`call my_stored_procedure(param1, param2)`

My strategy [based on my limited Regex knowledge] is to look for unique occurrences similar to:
call my_stored_procedure(

Exceptions are those that have the double-dash "--" comments at the start of the line before a "call".

My idea is that once I get the string above, I can just find the actual stored procedure name by using "call" and "(" as delimiters which I do in some post-preocessing.

In a stored procedure file there can be many variations of this call. There can be multiple spaces and/or tabs in between each of the whole words.

```
call     my_stored_procedure(param1, param2)
        call     my_stored_procedure(param1, param2)
call my_stored_procedure  (param1, param2)
call my_stored_procedure  (
 param1, param2)
call my_stored_procedure  ( param1, param2 )
-- call my_stored_procedure  (param1, param2)
--call my_stored_procedure  (param1, param2)
--call my_stored_procedure
-- jsmith call my_stored_procedure  (param1, param2)
```

I'm using the ASP.Net Regex engine and so far this is what I have:

`Regex rgxFindStoredProcedures = new Regex(@"(?<!.*--? *)(call|CALL)\s*([A-Za-z0-9-_\.]+)(\s*)\(",
RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Above Regex seems to work and I find all matches and excludes the first 3 commented out calls. However, it is including last commented call:

```
-- jsmith call my_stored_procedure  (param1, param2)
```

Does any body have an idea how I can filter out this last commented out call? My thought is to put a condition inside of

```
(?<!.*--? * some_condition_here)
```

which drops the match if there are words after the -- not equal to "call" but I can't quite figure out how to frame the Regex for this condition.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [start-of-line anchor `^`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w.aspx). Also,

- There's no need to include both `call` and `CALL` when you're already specifying `IgnoreCase`.
- Assuming `call` must be the first token on a line, you can skip the lookbehind
- You don't need to escape the period since it's already in a character class
- You can give a name to the part that matches the proc name and fetch it using the Match.Groups property

```
string pattern = @"^\s*call\s*(?<ProcName>[A-Za-z0-9_.]+)(\s*)\(";
var rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach(var m in rx.Matches(yourInput))
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["ProcName"].Value);
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. I tried your Regex but it also includes all those calls that have the "--" in front. As I mentioned in my post, I'm trying to filter out the calls that are commented out and I was having problems with the 8th call. I did use your approach of using <ProcName> so I do not have to do any post-processing downstream. That was real neat! Thanks for your input and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex that should do what you want.

```
^(?<!--.*?)\s*call\s+[A-Za-z0-9-_\.]+\s*\(
```

It matches the first five calls in your sample text.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Surprisingly I did  come up with a similar Regex except for the "call" part. Surprisingly, this one works when I use it in an ASP Regex tester http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx. However, when I put it in my C# code, it fails to find any matches. I'm still figuring out why this is the case.

Comment: I had to remove the "^" at the front since putting it fails to turn up any matches. Here is my current Regex combined with the suggestion from @jmh_gr:        `(?<!-- *?)\s*call\s*(?<ProcName>[A-Za-z0-9_.]+)(\s*)`. It's still not filtering out the last commented call.

Comment: Your last regex should work too, but You'll have to re-add the ^ at the beginning. Make sure you are using the RegexOption.Multiline, just like in jmh_gr's response. That option makes the ^ work on newlines instead of just the beginning of the string.